# Getting 'path' of previous URL from template

Tags: python, django-templates, django-urls

I know I can get the previous URL in the template by using the following:

```
{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}
```

But I want to know if I there's a way to get only the path and not the absolute URL 
(i.e **/my-page** instead of **http://localhost:8000/my-page**)

Like in the view we can do:

```
from urllib import parse
parse.urlparse(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')).path
```

Can I do something like that in the template as well?

**Update** (with more info): My usecase is to compare the previous url with another url within the same site to see if the user came in from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there isn't a direct way to do that in the template, so this is what I ended up doing in the template to check if a particular (relative) url is part of the previous (absolute) URL  :

```
{% url 'schoollist:add_school' as add_school_url %}
{% if add_school_url in request.META.HTTP_REFERER %} 
    Thanks for adding!
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to achieve this is to use `urlparse` to get components out of the referer URL, then get the relative path.

If you handle it with custom code this probably won't do much difference for basic cases but probably do some good with fancier edge cases:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
path = urlparse(referer).path
```

See: [Parse URLs into components](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)

Comment: I am doing that in the view but was wondering if there is a direct way to do something similar in the template